# CSV to dict in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv-like file that wants to transfer into dict in Python. Heres the sample file:

```
file start:
...
...
[section-1] # basically a setup info with <key-value> pair
date,2/16/2018
label,test3
size,25
...
[section-2] # contains test parameters and data
NO,parameter1,parameter2
1,50,30
2,-20,32
...
...
file end
```

I roughly have an idea of how to handle this file, to goal is to easily access each record. Something like dict maybe:

```
{'date':2/16/2018,
'label':test3,
'size':25,
'data':[{'NO':1,'parameter1':50,'parameter2':30}
        {'NO':2,'parameter2':-20,'parameter2',32}]
}
```

the usecase is I want to extract these data and load it into database. The [section-1] data will go to top-level table. And [section-2] data will be loaded into child table based on [section-1] info.

I'm very new to Python. Do you think this is the right direction to convert this file? Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What was the file created with?

Comment: Do you have  usecase in mind?

Comment: Do `file start` and `file end` literally appear in the file?

Comment: @chrisz it's generated from a tool

Comment: @Robᵩ No sir. I just add it to make i clear

Comment: How does one distingisgh between the two schema, name-value or header-line-followed-by-values? Or, will it always be two sections, always in the format described in the question?

Comment: @mad_ the usecase is I want to extract these data and load it into database. The [section-1] data will go to top-level table. And [section-2] data will be loaded into child table based on [section-1] info.

Comment: Check out the Python CSV package, including the csv_reader method.  I suspect that this will solve about half of your linkage problems.

Comment: @Robᵩ there's lieteraly '[section-1]' labeled in the file. So I'm thinking add a `if` statement

Comment: Out of curiosity - you have no control over the export file format? This one is a mess, a mash-up of `.ini` sections and `.csv` data...

Comment: @wiesion unfortunately no

Comment: I see - in this case Rob's answer is most probably the best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were me, I'd parse the file into sections using [`str.startswith('[')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith), and then use a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) to pass the resulting lines to [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) for the two sections, respectively.

Here is an example:

```
from csv import reader, DictReader
from pprint import pprint 

def lines_until_section_mark(f):
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('['):
            break
        if line.strip():
            yield line

with open('cfg.txt') as f:
    # Eat until first section mark
    for line in lines_until_section_mark(f):
        pass

    # Construct first dictionary from first sectoin
    d = dict(reader(lines_until_section_mark(f)))

    # Construct second dictionary from second section
    d['data'] = list(DictReader(lines_until_section_mark(f)))

pprint(d)
```

Input file:

```
[section-1] # basically a setup info with <key-value> pair
date,2/16/2018
label,test3
size,25

[section-2] # contains test parameters and data
NO,parameter1,parameter2
1,50,30
2,-20,32
```

Output:

```
{'data': [{'NO': '1', 'parameter1': '50', 'parameter2': '30'},
          {'NO': '2', 'parameter1': '-20', 'parameter2': '32'}],
 'date': '2/16/2018',
 'label': 'test3',
 'size': '25'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. One bonus question: How to handle parameters in [section-2] is changing? For example: this file may have "NO,p1,p2". Next file may [section-2] may have "NO,p2,p3". Is there a way that I can get parameter names without doing an iteration?

Comment: After running the above code, you can inspect `d['data'].keys()` to see the list of parameters. You can test if it changed like so: `if set(old_d['data'].keys()) != set(new_d['data'].keys()):`

Answer (score 1):

For parsing csv file you might want to use [dataknead](https://github.com/hay/dataknead) library. It works with Python 3 only.

You can install it like this: `pip install dataknead` (pip3 if you have different Python versions)

According to its documentation, let's assume you have a cities.csv like this:

```
city,country,population
Amsterdam,nl,850000
Rotterdam,nl,635000
Venice,it,265000
```

You can read it like this:

```
from dataknead import Knead
data = Knead("cities.csv").data()
```

The output of print(data) will be:

```
[{'city': 'Amsterdam', 'population': '850000', 'country': 'nl'}, {'city': 'Rotterdam', 'population': '635000', 'country': 'nl'}, {'city': 'Venice', 'population': '265000', 'country': 'it'}]
```

I suggest you to parse one section firstly. Then you can decide how to divide file's section. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use pandas you could do something like this. I am making a few assumptions about the data here. I am assuming size value equals the number of rows in your csv file. I am assuming you know the date and what you want to use as a name for the label.

This code will get you the rows in the csv file and create a dictionary for each row and put it in a list.

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {"date": '06/01/2018', "label":"test3","size":0}
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv')

row_list = []

for i, row in enumerate(df.values):
    my_dict['size']+=1
    row_dict = {}
    for i in range(0, len(row)):
        row_dict['col'+str(i)] = row[i]
    row_list.append(row_dict)

my_dict["data"] = row_list
print(my_dict)
```